# How to cross-compile elfutils for RISC-V?

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, riscv

I want to cross-compile `elfutils` for a RISC-V target and I get linker errors which I don't know how to solve. I use the [riscv-gnu-toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain).

#### Build `zlib`

`elfutils` is build against `zlib`, so I need to build it first:

```
CC=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu
make
make install
```

I use this prefix to have all RV64 libraries at the same place, so that the linker can find them easily (maybe wrong?). Building `zlib` seems to be successful, no errors and `libz.so.1` and other related files were placed into `/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib`.

#### Build `elfutils`

Executing the configure script with RISC-V host: (I also cross-compiled `zstd`, `bzip2` and `xz` with same CC and PREFIX as `zlib`)

```
$ ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --disable-libdebuginfod --disable-debuginfod
[checking a lot of stuff...]
=====================================================================
        elfutils: 0.183 (eu_version: 183)
=====================================================================

    Prefix                             : /usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu
    Program prefix ("eu-" recommended) : eu-
    Source code location               : .
    Maintainer mode                    : 
    build arch                         : x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  RECOMMENDED FEATURES (should all be yes)
    gzip support                       : yes
    bzip2 support                      : no
    lzma/xz support                    : yes
    zstd support                       : yes
    libstdc++ demangle support         : yes
    File textrel check                 : yes
    Symbol versioning                  : yes

  NOT RECOMMENDED FEATURES (should all be no)
    Experimental thread safety         : no
    install elf.h                      : no

  OTHER FEATURES
    Deterministic archives by default  : false
    Native language support            : yes
    Extra Valgrind annotations         : no
    libdebuginfod client support       : no
    Debuginfod server support          : no
    Default DEBUGINFOD_URLS            : 

  EXTRA TEST FEATURES (used with make check)
    have bunzip2 installed (required)  : yes
    have zstd installed                : no
    debug branch prediction            : no
    gprof support                      : no
    gcov support                       : no
    run all tests under valgrind       : no
    gcc undefined behaviour sanitizer  : no
    use rpath in tests                 : no
    test biarch                        : no
```

Then running `make` but I get this error:

```
$ make
make --no-print-directory all-recursive
Making all in config
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
Making all in lib
  CC       xstrdup.o
  CC       xstrndup.o
  CC       xmalloc.o
[...]
  CC       disasm_str.os
  CC       symbolhash.os
  AR       libasm_pic.a
  CCLD     libasm.so
Making all in debuginfod
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
Making all in src
  CC       readelf.o
  CCLD     readelf
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by ../libdw/libdw.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libzstd.so.1, needed by ../libdw/libdw.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: liblzma.so.5, needed by ../libdw/libdw.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `lzma_auto_decoder@XZ_5.0'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `ZSTD_isError'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `gzdopen'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `ZSTD_freeDCtx'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `gzread'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `ZSTD_createDCtx'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `lzma_end@XZ_5.0'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `gzerror'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `lzma_code@XZ_5.0'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `ZSTD_decompressStream'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libelf/libelf.so: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../libdw/libdw.so: undefined reference to `gzdirect@ZLIB_1.2.2.3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:686: readelf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:529: all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:445: all] Error 2
```

Why does the linker not find `libz.so.1`, `libzstd.so.1` and `liblzma.so.5`? The libraries are available as you can see here:

```
$ find /usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -name "libz.so.*"
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libz.so.1.2.11
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libz.so.1
$ find /usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -name "libzstd.so.*"
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libzstd.so.1
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libzstd.so.1.5.0
$ find /usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -name "liblzma.so.*"
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.5
/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblzma.so.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `LIBS="-lz -lzstd -llzma"`. The full configuration command looks like this:

```
LIBS="-lz -lzstd -llzma" ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --disable-libdebuginfod --disable-debuginfod --prefix=/usr/local/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I expected, that the flags were already set by the configure script and the makefiles ... but for some reason they are not if the libs are dynamically linked.

`src/Makefile.am`: (`zip_LIBS= -lzstd -llzma`)

```
[...]
if BUILD_STATIC
libasm = ../libasm/libasm.a
libdw = ../libdw/libdw.a -lz $(zip_LIBS) $(libelf) -ldl -lpthread
libelf = ../libelf/libelf.a -lz
else
libasm = ../libasm/libasm.so
libdw = ../libdw/libdw.so
libelf = ../libelf/libelf.so
endif
[...]
```